# I can't assign array to string variable in flutter

Tags: dart

```
 for (i = 0; i < arr1.length - 1; i++) {
  msg += arr1[i] + ",";
}
msg += arr1[i];
```

> I want to throw the data from the above array into a string variable named msg with a comma between them. But I am getting an error as below. How can I fix.
>
> _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' of 'other')

Comment: Write the declaration of the arr1 array

Comment: Also, use `msg += arr1.join(",")` instead. It does precisely what you are trying to do, and it's more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of what type of data is store in the array. If integers, or whatever else, you need to tranform to a string, with the `toString()` method

So:

```
msg += arr1[i].tostring() + ",";
```

If mixed types, you can check type with something like this:

```
if (arr1[i] is int) {
  msg += arr1[i].tostring() + ",";
}

if (arr1[i] is bool) {
  if (arr1[i]) { 
    msg += "1,";
  } else {
    msg += "0,";
}
 // And so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your `arr1` are `List<num>`. The `+` function on `num` does not take a `String` which are the error you are getting.

I would recommend doing the following for creating your `String` since it will automatically call `toString()` on your `num` element and does also make the code smaller:

```dart
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length - 1; i++) {
  msg += '${arr1[i]},';
}
msg += '${arr1[i]}';
```